# jQuery: set default save-as for image

Tags: jquery, image, save, rename

is there a possibility to change the default save-name when saving an image from my site?

For example:

if i do right-click and save an image, the name of the "real" image appear, like "photo_3874653_rtye6saJ.jpg". The question is: can I do something to set the default name "pippo.jpg"?

the only thing I came out with, was to use a button and use the Blob object and SaveAs() javascript function. but if there's a better solution without call HTML5 feature, it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to change HTTP headers when returning the image, this is one of the situations that `Content-Disposition` is designed for.

When returning the image, you will need to output an additional HTTP header of:

```
  Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pippo.jpg
```

More information on this header can be found in [RFC2616 Section 19 (Appendices)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), section 19.5.1.

Comment: so the only way is to serve each image from a php (/asp...) stream and set the header. thanks